Pytest: Selenium-Python script not running through command line
I developed Hybrid framework with Selenium-Python using pytest. Scripts are running fine but when try to run it through command line its giving an error. Earlier it was working fine after changing a laptop and install all software again and now its giving an error. Please see the error in below screenshot. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

can you share content of test_FileStatusPage.py

Sure, here it is.

import softest, from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pageObjects.HomePage import HomePage
from pageObjects.FileStatusPage import FileStatusPage
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup_teardown")
class Test_FileStatusPage(softest.TestCase):
def test_FileStatusPageTitle(self):
homePage = HomePage(self.driver)
fileStatusPage = FileStatusPage(self.driver)
fileStatusPage.click_OnFileStatus()
expected_Title="File Status"
self.soft_assert(self.assertEqual, fileStatusPage.titleFileStatusPage(), expected_Title)
self.assert_all()

Earlier the code was working fine with python 3.12 but after installing new versions of Python(3.12.3), Pycharm, Pytest may be giving an error. Can it be a reason?

I recommend you to check FileStatusPage which might override unittest in a wrong way because _testMethodName even has default value as 'runTest' by definition.

Thank you so much volkan,  yes its added softest.TestCase to the class into Page Object such as FormPage(BaseDriver,softest.TestCase):, I just removed softest.TestCase from class name.
